# Is it possible to get user's info from identityToken in Sign In with Apple with NodeJs?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sign-in-with-apple

For now, I implemented about sign in with apple feature but I don't wan't to store any credential in frontend. I want to send identityToken to backend and let backend get information about user. Is it possible to do that ?

Example flow.

[image: Example flow]

Comment: There is no apple endpoint to exchange an identity token for user information.  You can gather the user's name and email from the claims in the identity token you receive during the users *initial* signin with apple. These claims are not present in subsequent sign ins https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple#3383773